# Inserting multiple values using for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table book_hotel and columns  `book_id`, `name`, `contact`, and `booked_rooms` And i have the form to book a room. Not to be confused i have just fetched room from another table.

```
<form action="bookhotel.php" method="POST">
Name:<input type="text" name="name">    
Contact:<input type="text" name="contact">
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotel");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck[]' value=".$row['room'].">";
echo $row['room'];
echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Book" name="done">
</form>
```

If the user books 2 or 3 rooms. Inserting those rooms into booked_room column is my problem. I have tried the following code so far.  the loop is not executing and the value of $roomchecked is inserted as 1.what might be the problem?

```
 <?php
    $submit=isset($_POST['done']);
    if($submit)
    {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];

    $room=$_POST['mycheck'];

    $totalCheckboxChecked = sizeof($_POST['mycheck']);

    for($i=0;$i<$totalCheckboxChecked;$i++)
            {
           $roomchecked = $room[$i];
           $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
           $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO book_hotel (name,contact,booked_rooms) VALUES (?,?,?)");
           $stmt->bind_param("sii",$name,$contact,$roomchecked);
           $stmt->execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice, it's got prepared statements now!

Comment: try printing `$_POST` and share what you are getting;

Comment: `echo $room;` gives a notice `array to string conversion` and prints Array. @itzmukeshy7

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` share the response of this statement